# What does ‘railway’ mean in the following X?

Tags: meaning, difference

What does ‘railway’ mean in the following (is it sentence?) ?
What’s the difference between railway and track then?[image: railway and station]

Comment: There are no sentences here, just nouns and noun-phrases.

Comment: Also, please link or mention the dictionaries that you have used.

Comment: so is this a key to a map?

Answer (score 1):

**Railway** (or *railways) is a term encompassing all the elements involved in that mode of transport - the trains, engines, carriages, signals, stations, tracks and much else.

**Track** (or *tracks) refers to the metal rails on which the trains run.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_transport